# Where are the packages ?

Tags: package-management

When I ran `apt-get update` I get 404 not found.

This url returns 404 as well 
http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/utopic-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages

Does anyone have any idea about this situation ?

Thanks

Comment: Wait for a day or two for the server to get active again

Comment: According https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic  reached  "End of life" at July 23, 2015. So there is no security update.

Comment: But no security updates doesn't mean a 404 does it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Comment: EOL releases have their archives moved off the main server, so yes, it does mean a 404. You need to upgrade to a supported release.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 14.10 reached End of Life (EoL) on July 23, 2015 as stated by [Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases).  What you're seeing is them 'no longer supporting' that version of the distribution, ie: no longer providing downloads and updates.

This means that you will need to upgrade to a supported version.  You can use [Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) to select a version to which you can upgrade.

Long-Term Support (LTS) versions of Ubuntu have a longer time in which updates are provided.  You may decide to use LTS to prevent being forced into upgrades as often.

An unsupported and not-recommended option would be to try something such as [How to install software or upgrade from an old, unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)  This can cause really bad issues if you decide to later upgrade to a supported version.

To save you time and effort, **you should upgrade your version of Ubuntu, possibly to an LTS, in [a supported way](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/installing-upgrading.html)**.